# Factor $17i$ into a product of irreducible elements in $Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Messing with some algebra I've got:

$17i = (17+17i)(0.5+0.5i)$

I'm pretty sure this is not how I'm supposed to go about it.
Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: The important context is what ring you are doing "algebra" in.  The value $17i$ is clearly not a natural number, or even a real number, so you need to tell the Reader what ring to use (so that multiplication and irreducible elements are relative to a given ring).

Comment: Adding to hardmath, for example in $\mathbb C$ there aren't any irreducible elements as there are no non-units. Is your ring perhaps $\mathbb Z[i]$?

Comment: I'm sorry. The ring is indeed Z[i].

Comment: $17=(4+i)(4-i)$. Each is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ since it has prime norm.

Comment: Your method is flawed because $1/2 +i/2\notin\mathbb Z[i[$

Comment: I see. Also André it's not $17$ I'm trying to factor, it's $17i$... still stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice $17i = (4+i)(1+4i)$.  Each factor is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ since $1^2+4^2=17$, which is of course prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: wow.. that was quite trivial... so it's just guess and check?

Comment: That's how I did it.  It wouldn't hurt to print out a list of smaller Gaussian primes.  To be honest I'm terrible at these types of things and it always takes me forever to get them by guess and check.  I can never seem to get good intuiting in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Check here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html